# c# Thread.sleep sleep the current thread or the main thread?

Tags: c#

I'm using a multiThreading module which is quiet simple create a thread for each work sent in the list .
I'm passing the Thread which the work will be executed in to the work method .
and i'm catching any possible exception on my work method and i want to sleep the current thread  which the method is executed in if an exception is throwed.

Does the `Thread.sleep()` will do the trick or it will sleep the main Thread ?

Comment: It acts on the current thread.

Comment: @mnistic so there is no need to pass the Thread object to the method assuming that i'd only want to sleep if something goes wrong ?

Comment: That is correct no need to pass the thread.  The current thread context is known when you call thread.sleep

Comment: @TimRutter thank you

Comment: @Telly Correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thread.Sleep() sleeps the current thread.  Here is the msdn documentation:

[Thread.Sleep](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

"Suspends the current thread for the specified amount of time."

You may want to read the documentation as Thread.Sleep is not always the best approach for thread synchronisation

Answer (score 1):

makes current running thread to sleep

Answer (score 0):

It will make the current thread sleep as the documentation states:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t(v=vs.110).aspx